# Java jackson with MultipartFile

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Well, first I will explain what I'm doing, I using `Spring 4`, and I have to do one application for send some information with some attachments [PDF] and each one this files have one title, reference, etc. So, I made some mixup of objects `JSON` with `Jackson 2.3.3`.

So, before to put my code, I want to ask, can I use `MultipartFile` with `Jackson` (or maybe File)?
After I saw a lots of answers and information in the web about files and `JSON`, I am not clear if I can send files with `JSON` from the client side. And if it is possible, can I send this file in `JSON` object with one property that contain arrays of objects, each object will contain properties type string and the last one will be the file.

This is my `POJO`:

```
public class JsonDocBase{

    protected String tp="invoice";

    protected String cmt;

    protected String title;

    protected String lang="FR";

    protected String ref;

    protected MultipartFile file;

    -----get.. and set....
}


public class JsonOtherInformation{    
    String nm;

    String cmt;

    String orgMsgId;

    String tp;

    get.... set....

}
```

and this 2 objects will be in

```
public class JsonTest {

    private JsonOtherInformation info;

    private JsonDocFile doc[];

    set... get...

}
```

and my service spring is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/simple", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public MessageDb creatSimpleeActivationRequest(@RequestBody JsonTest jRequestSimple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that it is not a good idea to send file content in `JSON`. You can use `JSON` to return informations about file which could contain URL to download given file. This method is used in [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/). [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) is used to retrieve file metadata and if you want to download file content you can use [`downloadUrl`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource) property from metadata object. (See also [Drive SDK - Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads)).

But if you really want to return file's content in `JSON` you have to convert this content into `String`. You can use [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to encode content and client has to decode it after parsing. You can write custom serializer which can convert `MultipartFile` object into string.

Comment: Thank, well after some test i put the file in base64 in the client side and after in the server side change the base64 to file