# How to load file from client to serviec use AngularJS and Spring?

Tags: angularjs, spring, file-upload

How to load **image** and **other data**(for example: first name, second name and etc.) form client (use **AngularJS**) to server (use **Spring**) and save file and data on server?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i used jackson objetc with file[], the problem of this is that you have to transform the file in base64. So i will give you 2 option:

The first the easy one is use one module do it (you can find the information 2 or 3 modules here http://ngmodules.org/ with some example)

And the hardest way, make one transform went the image is loaded, get the base64 of the image, make your js object, send this to the  server (spring controller), have some tranform between base64 and java file and work with this if you have to.

I can put some code for the last one, but i dont have the code in this computer, but if you want tell me.

And for the first you have the examples code in the module.
This one my problem if you want to see if is the same

[Java jackson with MultipartFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486864/java-jackson-with-multipartfile)